# In the double slit experiment, why doesn't the electron interact with the wall or plate with the slits and therefore act like a particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

I always wondered if the electrons superposition is so fragile, why doesn't it interact with the wall or plate with the double slits? Do the slits have to be a certain size?

Comment: Is your question: why is there no wave function collapse upon interaction of the electron with the slit system? If so, please edit.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588887/feynman-s-electron-double-slit-experiment/589104#589104

Comment: The EM field controls it all. It's not fragile .... even single electrons eventually make the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Even with light, you will see the photons interacting with the slit(s) / apparatus:

[image]

Note the green laser everywhere that is not a screen. Those photons have left the experiment.

Looking at one slit, for simplicity, with the slit being defined as only the unblocked path, the entire diffraction pattern is cause by everything but the slit. E.g., in Huygens principle, the lack of emitters outside of the slit is what causes the plane wave to spread out--same for Feynman's path integral, but Huygens principle is easier to visualize.

Diffraction determines slit requirements--if the diffraction patterns of the two slits don't overlap, it will be hard to see the interference pattern. (Note: many sources show the particles moving straight through the slits when the path is known:
[image]

***THIS IS JUST WRONG***

A diffraction pattern for a $2d$ width slit *is* the interference pattern for two slits of width $d$ with zero separation: it's always a wave.

Experimentally:

There was an experiment in which the particles (idk what they were, but not light) interacted with some atom at the slit (maybe), and when it did, the coherence was lost with obvious results. It's on PSE, somewhere.

Theoretically:

I don't care for quantum woo, esp in pop culture. It's misleading. Quantum Mechanics is an approximation, irl, there are no particles. They are quanta of a quantum field (which has no need to be localized), and out best computational versions of that has a known initial state (a plane wave beam), and a known final state (outgoing wave, hitting a detector), and all we can do is calculate the scattering amplitude. No particles. No woo. No fuss (renormalization notwithstanding).

Comment: a down vote should really come with a comment, otherwise it's useless, since I don't care about points, but I would like to know the complaint, whether noob or expert (I'll learn something from either).

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I'm going to assume quantum mechanical equations of motion actually describe reality.

If a quantum system is evolving without interacting with other systems to a good approximation, then it may exhibit a process called quantum interference. This means that in general the system acts as if exists in multiple versions each one corresponding to different possible values of some measurable quantity and those versions interact so that all the versions affect the outcome, see "The Fabric of Reality" by David Deutsch, Chapter 2. Saying those versions actually exist is called the many worlds interpretation of quantum theory but it is just an implication of quantum theory:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568

When a system $S_1$ interacts with another system $S_2$, then information about some measurable quantity $X$ may be copied from $S_1$ to $S_2$. In general, this process suppresses interference between the different versions: a process called decoherence:

https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2832

https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189

After such an interaction, the state of the system is reset to a relative state corresponding to whatever version of the system you happen to see. Since interference isn't allowed between the different relative states you have no way to see a different relative state.

When an electron interacts with a screen with slits in it, some of the versions of the electron are absorbed by the plate. Other versions of the electron pass through the slits and aren't absorbed. This effectively copies information about the measurable quantity that answers the question: "was this electron absorbed by the screen or did it pass through the slits?" The versions of the electron that are absorbed don't interfere with those that pass through the slits. But two or more different versions of the electron that did pass through the slits can undergo interference.

Comment: we need to ban Many Worlds, imho.

Comment: @JEB  Agreed. This answer is all about MWI and has absolutely no relevance to the question itself - which is about the slit. One of my biggest gripes is that answers like this are not removed and/or authors are not warned. to stop this nonsense. Flagging does not seem to accomplish anything. At a minimum, anyone presenting an interpretation as an answer should be required to disclose it as such.

Comment: @JEB If you have a counterargument against the MWI then why not explain that it and convince MWI advocates to discard the theory?

Comment: Well _my_ counter argument to MWI is strictly phenomenological: No one has ever gotten tenure pushing MWI, including Hugh Everett and Sean Carroll.

Comment: @JEB That assertion, if true, is irrelevant to the truth or lack thereof of the MWI and has nothing to do with physics. I don't understand its relevance or why it would change anybody's mind.

Comment: Also Dieter Zeh was a professor and Everettian https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.09755 so your claim is false